# Uncaught TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Why am I getting the error above when I try to use the file-encryptor node module?

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please edit your question to include your code in case it's causing the issue. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference

Comment: Please update the question with more information. but based on what we have, did you include the fs module? 

Comment: more specificly, please provide a [mcve]. Question seeking debugging help must contain everything necessary to reproduce the issue, description of the expected and the actual behaviour